# Como hacer que mi array actualize datos a mi Base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un **scrip** de **php** donde puedan ver las diferentes direciones si estan ONLINE o OFFLINE y esto deseo que se deposite en una basa de datos de **MySql**
La estrutura de mi tabla solo tiene dos columnas que son: **Online_Status y ip**

Este es el codigo de php, cuando lo ejecuto si me muestra las IP si estan ONILINE o OFFLINE pero no me lleva nada ala base de datos.

```
<?php

    $conn=mysqli_connect("IP","login","password","baseDatos");
                   if (!$conn) {
                          die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                       
        
                    
            class CheckDevice {
            
                    public function myOS(){
                        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === (chr(87).chr(73).chr(78)))
                            return true;
            
                        return false;
                    }
            
                    public function ping($ip_addr){
                        if ($this->myOS()){
                            if (!exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 ".$ip_addr." 2>NUL > NUL && (echo 0) || (echo 1)"))
                                return true;
                        } else {
                            if (!exec("ping -q -c1 ".$ip_addr." >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?"))
                                return true;
                        }
            
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            
                 $ip_addr = array (10.49.xx.xx","10.49.xx.xx","10.49.xx.xx,"10.49.xx.xx");   
            
            
            $checkDevice = new CheckDevice();
            
            for($i = 0; $i < count($ip_addr); $i++)
            {
            if ($checkDevice->ping($ip_addr[$i]))
            
                    echo"ONLINE";
                else 
                
                     echo"OFFLINE";
            }

                  $instruccion_SQL  ="UPDATE `tbl_stacionbsl` SET  'Online_Status'= '$ip_addr' WHERE 
                     `tbl_stacionbsl`. 'IP'= '$ip_addr' ";
         
                 if (mysqli_query($conn, $instruccion_SQL)){
                  echo "";
            } 
            else {
                  echo "Error: " . $instruccion_SQL . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
```

Comment: En primer lugar, quieres actualizar un registro o insertar uno nuevo? Porque estás haciendo un UPDATE pero intentando planchar el mismo valor, es decir, no habrá cambios. Actualiza la pregunta para que podamos entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Lo que busco es un UPDATE en base ala IP que se me reflega pero no tengo idea de como hacer la parte donde hago el UPDATE @ Javier García

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con base en tu comentario, me parece que esto te ayudaría.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($ip_addr); $i++)
{
  $ip = $ip_addr[$i];
  
  if ($checkDevice->ping($ip))
    $status = 'ONLINE';
  else 
    $status = 'OFFLINE';

  $instruccion_SQL  = "UPDATE `tbl_stacionbsl` SET  'Online_Status'= '$status' WHERE `tbl_stacionbsl`. 'IP' = '$ip'";
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $instruccion_SQL)){
    echo "";
  } 
  else {
    echo "Error: " . $instruccion_SQL . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }

}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Ten en cuenta que esto realizará un update por cada ip de tu arreglo, teniendo en cuenta que en tu ejemplo son pocas direcciones, no hay tanto inconveniente. Sin embargo, si realizarás esta funcionalidad con muchas más ip´s, valdría la pena que almacenaras en dos arreglos `$online` y `$offline`, las ips para realizar únicamente dos consultas, usando la funcion `IN()` de mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo apreciar en tu código, estás tratando de insertar el arreglo de **IP's** en la base de datos, será que tendrás que poner tu **Query** dentro del **for** para que se inserte el status del usuario (ONLINE,OFFLINE), en mi opnion sería mas optimo utilizar en **bool** (0,1):

```
$checkDevice = new CheckDevice();
 for($i = 0; $i < count($ip_addr); $i++){
        if ($checkDevice->ping($ip_addr[$i]))
             $instruccion_SQL  ="UPDATE `tbl_stacionbsl` SET  'Online_Status'='$ip_addr' WHERE `tbl_stacionbsl`. Online_Status= 'ONLINE' ";
        else 
             $instruccion_SQL  ="UPDATE `tbl_stacionbsl` SET  'Online_Status'='$ip_addr' WHERE `tbl_stacionbsl`. Online_Status= 'OFFLINE' ";
        mysqli_query($conn, $instruccion_SQL)
        }
       
     
        mysqli_close($conn);
```